# Neo4j Rails 4 how to convert a class to use the GraphDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and I'm trying to understand how to convert a specific class to this technology.

My Class looks like this:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :study_version
  has_many :elements, :dependent => :destroy

  def self.ordinals(study_version_id)
    visits = Visit.where(study_version_id: study_version_id).order('ordinal asc')
    ordinal = 1
    visits.each do |item|
      item.ordinal = ordinal
      ordinal += 1
      item.save
    end
  end

end
```

I tried to convert it in this way but was not working good:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  include Neo4j::Timestamps

  has_many :out, :element, type: study_version

  def self.ordinals(study_version_id)
    visits = Visit.where(study_version_id: study_version_id).order('ordinal asc')
    ordinal = 1
    visits.each do |item|
      item.ordinal = ordinal
      ordinal += 1
      item.save
    end
  end

end
```

I would like to see what I'm doing wrong and what should be the right conversion in this class above. 
Thanks for help

```
Element code related to this issue:

class Element

    include Neo4j::ActiveNode
    include Neo4j::Timestamps

    has_one :out, :study_version, type: :study_version
    has_one :out, :visit, type: :visit
    has_one :out, :form, type: :form

    #belongs_to :study_version
    #belongs_to :visit
    #belongs_to :form

    def self.find_element(study_version_id, visit_id, form_id)
        elements = Element.where(study_version_id: study_version_id, form_id: form_id, visit_id: visit_id)
        return elements[0] if elements.count > 0
        return nil
    end

end
```

Comment: Remove inheritance from `ActiveRecord::Base`. Change `class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base `to `class Visit`. Should work this way

Comment: I changed and I have an error `500 (Internal Server Error)` I think is because I have to modify other stuff in my app to make it work

Comment: A few questions. Does your neo4j db/server is running? Have you created migrations for `Visit` and `Element`?

Comment: It is running. Migration could you explain, please?
Have I to create a migration file for it?
Here the migration files I have at the moment before Neo4j:
https://pastebin.com/CrSNndZk

Comment: Yes there is this functionality, here is [docs](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.2.x/Migrations.html). You don't _have to_, but it's helpful. 500 is http code, it doesn't give much information about what's wrong. Can you post a ruby exception that produces 500, please?

Comment: This cause the problem line 9 https://pastebin.com/sFkbztfF

Comment: I see, but what's the ruby exception is? What does it says? Look at the rails server logs

Comment: I have this in my log:
```Started POST "/elements/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-07 14:09:31 +0100
Processing by ElementsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"element"=>{"study_version_id"=>"369ae024-6703-46c1-9c0c-b3243a8d981b", "form_id"=>"30", "visit_id"=>"273"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ArgumentError - Form is not an ActiveNode model:
  app/controllers/elements_controller.rb:9:in `create'```

Comment: Oh, the problem is with you `Element` model. could you update the original post with code of you `Element code?`

Comment: I edited please take a look @NikitaMisharin

Comment: Thanks. It seems that you've forgotten to migrate `Form` model to neo4j

Comment: Yes that true I'm new I need to practice with this technology.
I will try to change the form to neo4j as well